# Display Bar Chart for Last week, Last Month, and Last Year Data from JSON using D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Could any one please let me know, how to display monthly, weekly, daily data from JSON.

Example:

> 1. How to obtain last 4 weeks of data from JSON (Monthly) ?
> 2. How to obtain last 12 months of data from JSON (Yearly) ?
> 3. How to obtain last 7 days of data from JSON (weekly) ?

JSON Example:

```
{"date" : "2016-06-16"}
...
...
{"date" : "2016-05-16"}
{"date" : "2016-04-16"}
```

Comment: Could you create a plnkr/jsfiddle/gist to be able to work with your code? I think you would need to create Date object from the string you have, then use `d3.nest`. If the Date object does not have enough functionalities, consider using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thank you. https://jsfiddle.net/sjsarama/j8hecu7o/

Comment: Please find the json data. Motor-date.json:

{
 "BC":[
  {
   
   "revision" : "83028",
   "value" : "107857",
   "date" : "2016-06-16",
   "location" : "global"
  },
  {
   
   "revision" : "82923",
   "value" : "107163",
   "date" : "2016-06-15",
   "location" : "global"
  },
  {
   
   "revision" : "82772",
   "value" : "107123",
   "date" : "2016-06-14",
   "location" : "global"
  }
]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved your code to [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JTZOgs3ThAjllY78VANS?p=preview) (I'm not a fan of jsfiddle; plnkr lets you create files as you want.

First, I noted you use d3 v3; I would recommend upgrading to v4 to enjoy the latest functionalities and improvements (but this is out-of-topic).

Second, I added a couple of lines (102 to 107) to create a nesting of data by month (as an example):

```
var byMonth = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){
      return d.month;
    })
    .entries(data["BC"])
console.log(byMonth);
```

Now, the object byMonth has a  `key` property, corresponding to the number of the month you already mapped, and a `values` property containing all values in said a month. You could now create/update a scale range using something like `scale.range(byMonth.map(function(d){return d.key;})`, use that scale for an axis, and plot your data accordingly. The same technique could be applied to the day or year property.

Comment: Thank you very much Hugues. I will check it.